# Images are not showing on Android device on react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am starting mobile developer and currently working on react native through expo.
The issue is that png images are not being rendered on an android device, but are shown in web browser.

`<Image source={require('./assets/Asset3.png')} style = {styles.samsa}/>`

Comment: Can you include the styles you reference with `styles.samsa` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to give fixed dimensions to image.Please take a look at the below question.
[How come my image is not showing - react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035899/how-come-my-image-is-not-showing-react-native)